# Suppressing Web Page Thumbnail in SLComposeViewController in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, facebook-ios-sdk, social-framework, slcomposeviewcontroller

We just discovered that in iOS 7, an SLComposeViewController instance (for example for Twitter) with a link and no image attached will try fetch a thumbnail preview of the web page that the URL points to.

In our case at least, this is not desirable.

**Is there a way to suppress the generation of that thumbnail?**

From my research, and the fact that the API diffs from iOS 6 to 7 show almost no changes for the Social Framework, I'm 99% sure that the answer is NO, but I thought I'd better at least post the question.

Hopefully this will be exposed in the future as a "displayThumbnail" property or the like, but we may have to just ride this one out if we can't change it now...

This also applies to the Facebook iOS SDK's implementation of their Native Dialogs as well (since it's basically a wrapper around the iOS APIs).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It does? I've not noticed that. But I've also been adding pictures, so maybe it is suppressed if you add a picture.